# Is it possible to use `findFiles` api for files outside the workspaceFolders?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/42a8653e39e72344b20a1a27c038bda02f1e82ea/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L10624-L10641

```
vscode.workspace.findFiles()
```

Seems to be only returning results from `workspaceFolders`. How to use it outside the workspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible with `vscode.RelativePattern`

```
await workspace.findFiles(new RelativePattern('C:/notes', '**/*.md'), '**/node_modules/**');
```